# Python Zipfile - is entire file unzipped to memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have some code which I am using to open a large zip which contains some csv files and then parse them.

I am using this code below but I am now wondering if I am actually unzipping the entire file into memory and then extracting the file contents to disk as well, after which I read the files in one by one.

```
def unzip_file(file_path):

    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')

    extracted = zip_ref.namelist()

    zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/extracts')

    zip_ref.close()

    return extracted
```

Is this actually unzipping the files and their contents into memory and then extracting the files straight to disk? I use the `extracted` variable afterwards as it contains a list of the file names I need to process but I dont also want to open each file into memory and then read them again.

Comment: Are you concerned that the files stay in memory after you returned extracted? So you are thinking that if you open them again, you now have allocated the same file in memory twice at the same time?

Comment: Yes thats it, I am wondering if I have actually unzipped the contents to memory (which is millions of rows), then returned the list of names and then I am just opening the unzipped files from the file system one at a time and then parsing them.

Comment: `extracted` is just a list of the contents of the archive. If you don't want to extract them to disk here, don't call `extractall()`—you can still return the name list.

Comment: Well I want to do the most efficient thing, and I am sure if what I have done is now correct, if I dont need to call `extractall()` but can still parse the list of files that seems to be better than calling it only to then use it to read back in the files from the filesystem?

Comment: Forgot to mention that just opening the zip file and reading the namelist doesn't extract the files into memory.

Comment: @berimbolo if you want more efficiency, you can extract-and-parse as iteration steps (iterate on infolist() and get the content of the current item via `open()` or `read()`) instead of extracting everything to the FS then re-reading files one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concern is that you are wasting memory or being inefficient in the manner you are reading the files when extracting them. The answer to if you're doing anything "wrong" is simply: "No". Your code is correct and it does not keep files in memory after you have finished the function call.

A few notes on what you can improve though.

### Use Context Managers to Automatically Close File

The `ZipFile` is also a context manager and it is generally considered best practice to use it to make sure that files are closed and cleaned up from memory correctly. Instead of calling `.close()` manually you could do the following:

```
with ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("/tmp/extracts")
```

It will then automatically close the file after the context manager is done, and make sure that nothing is stored in memory.

Since you close the file, you do not have to fear that it will stay in memory.

### Read Files without Extracting

Since you are extracting the files to a `/tmp/` folder, I guess(?) that you actually don't want to store the files on disk. Perhaps all you want to do is to read the data and do something with it.

You can read each file within the zip file without extracting them to disk.

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt') as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
```

This might be a better solution depending on what you want to achieve. You can see more from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open).

Comment: Yes you are exactly right, I extract them to /tmp because I only want to parse them and insert into mongodb, at the the end of the import process I simple remove all the files in the /tmp/extracts directory anyway.